# SQLAlchemy - Update if object has a PK

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is there a way to inform SQLAlchemy that it should perform an update if all the objects in a graph do have the PK present?

**EDIT:**
By PK I mean PK value

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your use of "graph" here, if you mean table then I think you need something like this:

```
pk_exists_query = session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.id != None).all()
for record in pk_exists_query:
    record.foo = #whatever
```

If you want to update the records to have the same value that's even easier and you can just something like this:

```
session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.id != None).update({'foo':'bar'})
```